# Filtering prefetch_related() to optimize data set

Tags: django, optimization

I'm hitting a performance issue on my overview page and am looking for some help.

Below is my current query which is working just fine: the page gets rendered in less than 2 seconds with n=12 queries in total. Great so far.

```
person_occurrences = Occurrence.objects\
    .filter(date__year=first_day_in_month.year, date__month=first_day_in_month.month,
            real_time_in__isnull=False, real_time_out__isnull=False)\
    .distinct('person')

present_persons = Person.objects.filter(occurrence__in=person_occurrences).order_by('last_name')\
    .prefetch_related('occurrence_set') \
    .prefetch_related('fooindex_set') \
    .prefetch_related('servicevoucher_set')\
    .prefetch_related('stay_set__hospitalization_set') \
    .prefetch_related('invoice_set')
```

However I need to access one more nested model under `occurrence_set`:

```
    .prefetch_related('occurrence_set__meal_noon_options') \
    .prefetch_related('occurrence_set__meal_noon_partner_options')
```

When I add these two, my page takes over **25 seconds** to load with n=14 queries in total.

When debugging (django-debug-toolbar), I noticed the executed query for the latter is:

> SELECT ••• FROM "stays_mealoption" INNER JOIN
>   "edc_occurrence_meal_noon_options" ON ("stays_mealoption"."id" =
>   "edc_occurrence_real_meal_noon_options"."mealoption_id") WHERE
>   "edc_occurrence_real_meal_noon_options"."occurrence_id" IN (32930,
>   32931, 32932, 32933, 32934, 32935, 32936, 32937, 32938, 32939, 32940,
>   32941, 32942, 32943, 32944, 32945, 32946, 32947, 32948, 32949, 32950,
>   32951, 32952, 32953, 32954, 32955, 32956, 32957, 32958, 32959, 32960,
>   32961, 32962, 32963, 32964, 32965, 32966, 32967, 32968, 32969, 32970,
>   32971, 32972, 32973, 32974, 32975, 32976, 32977, 32978, 32979, 32980,
>   32981, 32982, 32983, 32984, 32985, 32986, 32987, 32988, 32989, 32990,
>   32991, etc.

The occurrence_id's are apparently *all* IDs that exist in my DB, currently over 10.000. Therefore the returned data set is **huge** and is slowing down the page.

I tried to limit the occurrences by filtering on year/month in my 2nd query, i.e. `Person.objects.filter(occurrence__in=person_occurrences, occurrence__date__month=first_day_in_month.month, occurrence__date__year=first_day_in_month.year).order_by('last_name')\ <snip>`, but that didn't work: `prefetch_related()` still fetches all `occurrence` objects.

I also looked into Django 1.7+'s [Prefetch()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-objects) objects:

```
.prefetch_related(Prefetch('occurrence_set__meal_noon_partner_options',
                           queryset=occurrence.objects.filter(date__month=first_day_in_month.month, date__year=first_day_in_month.year))) \
.prefetch_related(Prefetch('occurrence_set__meal_noon_partner_options',
                           queryset=occurrence.objects.filter(date__month=first_day_in_month.month, date__year=first_day_in_month.year)))
```

... but there I get complaints that the queryset should not be of `Occurrence` but should be of `MealOption`.

Any idea on how to properly optimize?

Using Postgresql and Django 1.10.

Comment: You get complaints about the queryset not being MealOption because you are fetching Occurrences instead of MealOptions, so maybe you can reverse that to be mealoption.objects.filter(occurrence__date__month=... or so?